# Laravel missing CSRF token via Ajax call and AWS load balancer

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

Since I moved a Laravel 5.4 project to AWS, most of the Ajax request is throwing an error `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68`. I don't know what else I can do to fix it. Another info that could be important is that I am using a load balancer between 2 servers.

In all request, I send the **X-CSRF-TOKEN** on the header and the **_token** at the form data.

Sometimes the request works but sometimes don't.

Thanks

Comment: *"Another info that could be important is that I am using a load balancer between 2 servers."*  Yes, that's significant.  Is it a Classic ELB, or an Application Load Balancer?

Comment: Classic ELB @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Have you configured the balancer for ["stickiness?"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Michael-sqlbot I solved the issue in the same day using the same solution as you wrote. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by enabling the stickiness as @Michael-sqlbot has written above.